# Изменить формат вывода времени

Tags: python, дата, время, datetime

Делаю программу, которая прибавляет время:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  # Использую эту библиотеку
import math
hh = int(input())  # Ввожу часы в формате Int
mm = int(input())  # Ввожу минуты в формате Int
s = int(input())   # Тут еще одна нужная мне переменная
t1 = math.ceil((s / 100) * 7.25)  # Тут через предыдущую переменную считаю количество минут которые надо прибавить
date = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1, hour=int(hh), minute=int(mm))  # Собственно присваиваю
date += timedelta(minutes=t1)  # И наконец прибавляю
print(date.strftime("%H:%M"))  # Вывожу
```

Все хорошо, кроме последней строчки - дело в том, что мне нужно выводить время в 24 - часовом формате, но с условием, что вместо `09:03` программа должна вывести `9:03`

**Пример(входные данные):**

*7*

*50*

*1000*

**Ожидаемый результат:**

*9:03*

**Вывод:**

*09:03*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учимся читать документацию: вместо `%H` используй `%-H` (но работает не на всех осях).

Если не работает, то можно применить примерно такой костыль:

```
output = date.strftime("%H:%M")
if output[0] == "0":
    output = output[1:]
print(output)
```

Comment: Не работает)Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Стандартных нет. Только вручную форматировать.

Comment: Так мой вопрос и заключается в этом, как это сделать?) Извиняюсь за излишнюю прямоту вопроса, но просто очень нужно) Спасибо!

Comment: Сделать элементарно: присвоить переменной, если первый символ "0", то удалить его.

Comment: s = str(date.strftime("%H"))
    m = str(date.strftime("%M"))
    if s[0] == "0":
        fixed = s[0:]
    print(s, ":", m, sep="")

Comment: Код в комментариях нечитаем (к тому же в нем ошибка/опечатка) Зачем приводить к строке то, что уже и есть строка? Я уже дополнил ответ.